# How can I retain format in a page webscraped with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, shiny, rvest

There is an example web page I wish to scrape to obtain a lyric where I want to replicate the layout in a Shiny app, possibly within a `renderUI()` function

```
People all over the world (everybody) 
Join hands (join)
Start a love train, love train
People all over the world (all the world, now)
Join hands (love ride)
Start a love train (love ride), love train

The next stop that we make will be soon (etc)
```

Using rvest I can get the nodesets and the plain text but am unclear the best way to display the text in its original format.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://play.google.com/music/preview/Ttyni4p5vi3ohx52e7ye7m37hlm?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV7oXtqtvNAhVB5GMKHTnHDZEQr6QBCBsoADAB"

 read_html(url) %>%
   html_nodes("p")

{xml_nodeset (6)}
[1] <p>People all over the world (everybody)<br/>Join hands (join)<br/>Start         a love train, love train<br/>People all over the world (a ...
[2] <p>The next stop that we make will be soon<br/>Tell all the folks in Russia, and China, too<br/>Don't you know that it's time to g ...

read_html(url) %>%
   html_nodes("p") %>% 
   html_text()

[1] "People all over the world (everybody)Join hands (join)Start a love train, love trainPeople all over the world (all the world, now)Join hands (love ride)Start a love train (love ride), love train"                                                                                                                                                                                                            
[2] "The next stop that we make will be soonTell all the folks in Russia, and China, tooDon't you know that it's time to get on boardAnd let this train keep on riding, riding on throughWell, well"
```

TIA

Comment: html_text appears to be taking out all html tags, including the break lines. Can you not just use gsub to replace <br/> with \n?

Comment: Perhaps remove the tracker bits from the query string to avoid helping google have evidence of ToS violating scraping activity across multiple database tables… `https://play.google.com/music/preview/Ttyni4p5vi3ohx52e7ye7m37hlm?lyrics=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV7oXtqtvNAhVB5GMKHTnHDZEQr6QBCBsoADAB`

Comment: @hrbrmstr Tx for tip. So that would be the ved=0ahUKEwiV7oXtqtvNAhVB5GMKHTnHDZEQr6QBCBsoADAB?

Comment: Oh, no. Twas the `utm_` stuff (I shld have made that clearer, apologies). The URL I posted in the prev comment works and doesn't cause extra tracker info stored in their analytics stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can borrow `xml2::xml_contents`, which returns all child elements, both text and tags, separated. As `rvest` uses `xml2` for things like `read_html`, the function should already be available without explicitly calling `library(xml2)` (but go ahead if you like).

If you add in `purrr::map`, you can nest the children of each `<p>` tag, which lets you separate out verses. If you don't like one more package, in this instance it's mostly the same as `lapply` except the last one, so I've added base versions in the comments.

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr) # for `map`

url <- "https://play.google.com/music/preview/Ttyni4p5vi3ohx52e7ye7m37hlm?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV7oXtqtvNAhVB5GMKHTnHDZEQr6QBCBsoADAB"

url %>% read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes("p") %>% 
    # For each node, return all content nodes, both text and tags, separated. From xml2.
    map(xml_contents) %>%    # or lapply(xml_contents)
    # For each nexted node, get the text. Here, this just reduces "<br />" tags to "".
    map(html_text) %>%       # or lapply(html_text)
    # For each list element, subset to non-empty strings.
    map(~.x[.x != ''])       # or lapply(function(x){x[x != '']})

## [[1]]
## [1] "People all over the world (everybody)"         
## [2] "Join hands (join)"                             
## [3] "Start a love train, love train"                
## [4] "People all over the world (all the world, now)"
## [5] "Join hands (love ride)"                        
## [6] "Start a love train (love ride), love train"    
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "The next stop that we make will be soon"             
## [2] "Tell all the folks in Russia, and China, too"        
## [3] "Don't you know that it's time to get on board"       
## [4] "And let this train keep on riding, riding on through"
## [5] "Well, well" 
## 
## ...
```

Comment: OK Thanks very much that's looking good. However,other than the grocery kind, I'm unfamiliar how to handle lists. How do I get the verses back so that there is a <br> between [[1]][1] and [[1]][2] etc. and then a <p> between [[1]] and [[2]] Tx

Comment: If you're not going to do anything with it besides reserve it as HTML, you can just slice out the code: `url %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('p') %>% paste(collapse = '\n') %>% write(file = 'song.html')`. I'm not sure what advantage your website is gaining over the existing one, though.

Comment: Your comment provides exactly what I want. FYI it will form part of a shiny flexdashboard app which has features not shown on the existing one